# need posix cksum in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to find an npm package or Node.js implementation of Posix cksum such that it will produce this (example) output:

```
cksum("SheetJS") = 2052521593
```

This is just an example invocation. There seem to be many algorithms out there for CRC generation. This one corresponds to the Posix implementation. I need to generate a checksum in Node.js that will match the checksum being generated on machines that are using the Posix/UnixUtils/GNU cksum implementation.

```
cksum --version
cksum (GNU textutils) 2.0

cat foo.txt
SheetJS

cksum foo.txt
2052521593 7 foo.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the logic behind that? I don't see a correlation or explanation off the top of my head...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cksum

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
npm install cksum -save
...

const cksum = require('cksum');
let buffer = cksum('SheetJS');
let thecrc = parseInt(buffer.toString('hex'),16);
console.log(thecrc);
...
2052521593
```